# Removing the code with preprocessor in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I have .net C# application. In the application have two set of code for different client.

We were thinking of removing the part of code through preprocessor. Diabling the part with config file parameter is not an option for us.

We want simple setup like:

```
#define DEBUG
//....
#if DEBUG
  Console.WriteLine("Debug version");
#endif
```

The only issue is, our part of code is distributed into multiple files and multiple projects in the solution.

So we want to define globally the preprocessor “DEBUG” at one place. Preferably in project property or something.

What is the best option for us?

Comment: Without knowing your reasoning I would strongly advice against using this practice. Refactoring out the client specifics to an interface and providing implementations for each customer would probably save you maintainance headaches.

Comment: We handle this type of thing exactly like paulroho suggested.  It is worlds away better than trying to handle different builds

Answer (score 3):

Look for "Conditional Compilation Symbols" on the "Build" page of the project property dialog.  You can set it per-build configuration.